# My login php form didnt enter in my 'if $result==true"

Tags: php, authentication, var-dump

i do a login form for enter in the backoffice but whatever i put in login and password, i get all the time the redirection in

```
else    {
            header('Location:   ../auth/login.php?error=1');
```

My code is :

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('../connexion.php');   

$login = isset($_POST['login']) ? $_POST['login']   : null; 
$pass       = isset($_POST['mdp'])  ? ($_POST['mdp'])   : null; 

var_dump($_POST);

$sql = 'SELECT  *   FROM    users   WHERE   login = \'' . $login . '\'  AND     pass    =   \'' . $pass . '\'';

var_dump($sql);
$req = $connexion->prepare($sql);   

var_dump($req);
$result = $req->execute(array('login' =>    $login, 'mdp' =>    $pass));

var_dump($result);  
if($result == true ){
         $_SESSION['logged']    = true; 
         header('Location:  ../admin_panel.php');
     }  else    {
                header('Location:   ../auth/login.php?error=1');
}
?>
```

My vardump in $result return always true

**

```
array (size=2)
  'login' => string 'dsfc' (length=4)
  'mdp' => string 'sdf' (length=3)
string 'SELECT  *   FROM    users   WHERE   login = 'dsfc'  AND pass    =   'sdf'' (length=57)
object(PDOStatement)[2]
  public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT    *   FROM    users   WHERE   login = 'dsfc'  AND pass    =   'sdf'' (length=57)
boolean true**
```

I didnt understand why $result is true whatever i put in my form.

Thanks for helping !

----------------EDIT----------------

I change a bit my prepare, but still dont work, but now my vardump $_POST didnt read what i put in my form

```
    $sql = 'SELECT  *   FROM    users   WHERE   login   =   :login  AND pass    =   :mdp';

var_dump($sql);
$req = $connexion->prepare($sql);   

var_dump($req);
$result = $req->execute(array(':login' =>   $login, ':mdp' =>  $pass));
```

Comment: read `prepare` statements carefully.

Comment: Why are you including directly your variables into the `$sql` statement instead of using `execute` which is made for that ? It could cause major security issues !

Comment: I do that after reading correctly prepare() 

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE   login   =   :login  AND pass    =   :mdp';

var_dump($sql);
$req = $connexion->prepare($sql); 

var_dump($req);
$result = $req->execute(array(':login' =>   $login, ':mdp' =>  $pass));

Answer (score 0):

try to use triple equal (===)

```
if($result === true ){
//something here
}
```

Comment: Hm, look like didnt effect i got this now :        

array (size=2)
  'login' => string 'sdfsdfsdf' (length=9)
  'mdp' => string 'sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs' (length=22)
string 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE   login   =   :login  AND pass    =   :mdp' (length=68)
object(PDOStatement)[2]
  public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE   login   =   :login  AND pass    =   :mdp' (length=68)
boolean true